# Prevent manual text entry in a PyGTK SpinButton

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk

Using Python 3.8, GTK 3.0, I would like to prevent the user from manually entering text in a `Gtk.SpinButton()`, while leaving the `+/-` / `up/down` portion of the SpinButton functional.  Is this possible?

I tried `set_editable(False)`, but that disables the entire widget, including the up/down arrows.

I thought maybe there's a way to access the `Gtk.Entry()` portion of the SpinButton, and call `set_editable(False)` only on that child, but have not found it yet.

**EDIT: Here is some demo code**

The goal is to have the text entry field of spin1 disabled (ideally insensitive, so the cursor cannot appear when clicked), while the +/- buttons still work, and still update the value.  spin2 & spin3 go too far, as even the +/- buttons don't work.

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class SpinButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="SpinButton Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        grid.set_column_spacing(6)
        grid.set_row_spacing(4)
        self.add(grid)

        adj1 = Gtk.Adjustment()
        adj1.configure(0, 0, 100, 10, 10, 0)
        spin1 = Gtk.SpinButton()
        spin1.set_adjustment(adj1)
        grid.attach(spin1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        adj2 = Gtk.Adjustment()
        adj2.configure(0, 0, 100, 10, 10, 0)
        spin2 = Gtk.SpinButton()
        spin2.set_adjustment(adj2)
        spin2.set_editable(False)
        grid.attach(spin2, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        adj3 = Gtk.Adjustment()
        adj3.configure(0, 0, 100, 10, 10, 0)
        spin3 = Gtk.SpinButton()
        spin3.set_adjustment(adj3)
        spin3.set_sensitive(False)
        grid.attach(spin3, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        label1 = Gtk.Label(label='Basic Spin')
        label1.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        grid.attach(label1, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        label2 = Gtk.Label(label='Editable=False')
        label2.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        grid.attach(label2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        label3 = Gtk.Label(label='Sensitive=False')
        label3.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        grid.attach(label3, 2, 1, 1, 1)


win = SpinButtonWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code you can provide so that others can provide a detailed response suited to your desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `spin1` to ignore most key presses.

Change the imports:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
```

Add the following method to `SpinButtonWindow` class:

```
def key_handler(self, widget, event):
    key = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if key in ['Up', 'Down', 'Page_Up', 'Page_Down']:
        return widget.im_context_filter_keypress(event)
    # Ignore other keys.
    return True
```

Connect this method to the spinbox:

```
spin1 = Gtk.SpinButton()
spin1.connect("key-press-event", self.key_handler)
```

Comment: Thank you @RolandSmith, very useful info.  Accepting, as it answers my question, but I'm curious if there's a way to prevent the cursor from appearing when clicking in the text entry portion, so the user doesn't get the impression they can edit.  I tried intercepting the `button-press-event` but I couldn't find a way to distinguish between clicking the entry portion vs clicking the +/- buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure if the cursor *can* be suppressed independantly from the input focus.  At least nothing obvious in the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/SpinButton.html#Gtk.SpinButton) caught my eye. A possibility might be to change the color of the cursor to the background color.